# Form Recognizer SDK AnalyzeResult.from_dict methoid returns an emoty object

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

I'm manually calling a form rest api endpoint to analyze a large PDF document and I use the rest api to receive the results. I'm using the api_version = "2023-02-28-preview" model = "prebuilt-layout. The response comes back successfully with a large json document containing the results. I then try to convert the json to an an AnalyzeResult, but get an empty returned object

```
headers = {
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': FR_key
}

params = {
    'api-version': api_version
}
url = f"{endpoint}formrecognizer/documentModels/{FR_MODEL}/analyzeResults/{FR_resultId}"
response = durable_get(url, headers, params)   

# try to get rsult into the sdk class
result_dict = json.loads(response.text)
sdk_result = AnalyzeResult.from_dict(result_dict)

print("done")
```